# Canvas ignoring parent size

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have a page which displays an HTML canvas element inside a container. Since the image displayed in the canvas can be far bigger than the space I have, I forced the size of the container and used its overflow property to scroll the contente of the canvas. While both the container and the scrollbar are displayed correctly, the canvas simply ignores it.

My HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
   Some content
</div>
<div class="the_wrapper">
    <div class="canvas_wrapper">
       <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="another_element">
         Some other content
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
 .sidebar{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 20vw;
    float: left;
 }

.the_wrapper{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80vw;
    float: right;
}

.canvas_wrapper{
    height: 60vh;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.another_element{
    height: 40vh;
}
```

This is what I want
[image: This is what I want]

But all I get is this

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: `.canvas_wrapper` and `.canvasWrapper`.dont match.

Comment: it's working as you want on my chrome. May be anything else causing the problem. Can you share fiddle for this ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tbhc2em4/ something like this? seems to work in firefox & chrome, just change the `with` to fit your needs... (*not posting as answer as I'm not sure you want to use percents*)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/un4L5tfz/ it's working, you can check here

Comment: In what browser? In firefox works

Comment: Both solutions don't work in my page. I suppose it's something related to the canvas controller.

Answer (score 0):

.the_wrapper do not need a float set to right.

```
 .the_wrapper{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80vw;
    float: right; // Don't do that
}
```

Just do this

```
.the_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80vw;
}
```

I also reset some properties to get the result of your first example.

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Here the snippet result :

```css
 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

.sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 20vw;
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid #000;
 }

.the_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80vw;
}

.canvas_wrapper {
    height: 60vh;
    border: 3px solid green;
}

.another_element {
    height: 40vh;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">Some content</div>
<div class="the_wrapper">
    <div class="canvas_wrapper">Canvas
       <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="another_element">Some other content</div>
</div>
```

You can also try it in https://jsfiddle.net/lofeed/6n983g7x/4/

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper is set to float to the right, meaning that all available space will be included within it.